# how to add comments to web page in SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. I have created some pages (rich text with picture), and I am wondering how to allow people to add comments to web pages (showed at bottom of the page), just like we can add comments to blog page?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I used SharePoint Designer and inserted a List Form webpart. First of all when I went to edit a comment, it was displaying the drop down box where I could assign the comment to a different idea. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYAFO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYAFO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- option 1) use a blog site definition
  which allows people to add comments
  to a blog post
- option 2) develop
  custom control (requires development
  skills) to facilitate this
  functionality
- option 3) check if there are any 3rd party vendors offering this as a product

Comment: "use a blog site definition which allows people to add comments to a blog post" -- I have already using publishing portal template to create the site, how to use your blog site template based on my existing publishing portal site?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a custom list that is viewed on the page using the page filter to make sure only those comments related to the page are viewable. The hard part is going to be putting the form on the page to allow them to comment. I know that you can use jQuery to set the value of a field in the form, so that you can have it default to the value needed to ensure the filter works properly, see this article for reference: http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/06/15/quick-and-easy-use-jquery-to-set-a-text-field%e2%80%99s-value-on-a-sharepoint-form/

Lori

Comment: Thanks Lori, "the page filter to make sure only those comments related to the page are viewable" -- is it possible to create a list on each page which needs comments?

Comment: I like the idea, but I wonder what the permissions configuration on that list would look like

Comment: I want to make all non-anonymous users to be able to add comments, is that feasible from technical point of view?

Comment: For the idea of using list, my current confusion is, I want to create a list looks like normal comment style of a page/blog, like the blog on this one, 

http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-active-directory-migrations.html

but the list I created looks like a data sheet. Any ideas to create a customer list which looks like comment style?

Comment: Yes, you could create a list for each page and display only that list. That would save you from having to use jQuery for the field population. As far as the formatting, you could do a couple of different things. You could use jQuery to change the formatting of the list, or use SPD to make a dataview of the list and format it the way you want.

Comment: Hi Lori, can you recommend a good book about jQuery?

Comment: jQuery in Action - http://www.manning.com/bibeault/

Comment: Cool, Jaap! Good book.

Answer (score 1):

Option 4) Use SP Designer

I've been able to do this before with just SP Designer.  There are two things to do here.  One, displaying comments that have been added and two, providing a box for people to add comments.

[This blog post here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/sharepoint-conference-building-a-sharepoint-designer-mashup-part-1) has helped me in the past add comments to the bottom of a page.  Just create a list with a lookup column and follow the directions in the blog post to display all comments for the item you are currently viewing.

Here's some of what I wrote on an internal blog post explaining my experiences in creating the ability to add comments at the bottom of a page which I think could be helpful.  In this case it was a list of ideas.

"Having the ability to add a comment at the bottom of the page wasn't that bad.  I used SharePoint Designer and inserted a List Form webpart.  I was quickly adding comments.  The problem was I had to select which idea I was adding a comment for.  I found [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140720084957/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/06/13/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field.aspx) which helped me add some javascript to automatically select the idea I was currently viewing.  Then I could hide that row of data from the form and people won't be able to change it or see that it's an option.

I still needed it to come back to the page I was on.  After submitting the comment it was wanting to go back to the full list of ideas.  I found [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7aff3de2-4250-47ac-9175-2fdc0a685005/) which worked exactly like I needed it to.

The editing of comments ended up turning into its own animal.  First of all when I went to edit a comment, it was displaying the drop down box where I could assign the comment to a different idea.  I didn't want this to be shown. But I wanted things to be easy and use the default sharepoint control and not go down the route of creating a new list form webpart like I did for the add comment.  I found [this post](http://sharepointsherpa.com/2008/08/26/sharepoint-2007-hiding-fields-on-newformaspx-and-editformaspx-the-easy-way/) which when added to the page, hid that row of data with ease.

I also had the issue when editing comments that it wouldn't take me back to the previous page I was on.  It kept sending me to the main list of ideas.  If you add an onclick event like this:  `onclick="GoToLink(this); return false;"` to your anchor tags, then SharePoint will add a source querystring parameter to the url and the page will return to that source parameter.  I ended up copying some of the gotolink code from the core.js onto the bottom of my page so that it would force the source to be the current url.  Once that was done, I was returning nicely to the page I was previous at."

Answer (score 0):

You can using commenting service that provided complete path, support and prevent from spammers. Such as Disqus.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. While your post may answer the Question it doesn't go into enough depth to be easily understood, please consider revising your answer so that it may or may not be accepted in its fullest.

Comment: Yes, exactly as Hugh says. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more information on how to answer.